# Set Input required based on Parent class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have some php that adds a class (bg-success) to a `<td>` if its value is used for something else. In every `<td>` is a text input. How can I make the input required if the class of the td is "bg-success"?

```
<tr>
   <td class="border text-center">
      <input type="text" name="1">//not Required
   </td>
   <td class="border text-center bg-success">
      <input type="text" name="2">//needs to be required
   </td>
   <td class="border text-center bg-success">
      <input type="text" name="3">//needs to be required
   </td>
...
```

I have tried a few variations of this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var parents = document.getElementsByClassName("bg-success");
    for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
        var parent = parents.item(i);
       parent.find(">:first-child").attr('required', '');
    }
});
```

It hasn't liked any version I have tried and maybe I'm not even close to correct. It doesn't like whatever I put after parent or `parents.item(i)`.

I know I could move the class to the input but I like it being more like a border.

Full transparency, this is my first coding project and I am sure that I am doing everything the hard way. This site has helped me figure out a lot of things. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `It hasn't liked` Is there an error or does it just not work?

Comment: [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) is a jQuery function, not a native DOM function. You probably have a console error about that

Comment: So is `.find()`. The DOM function is `.querySelector()`.

Comment: It's always confusing when you jump back and forth between jQuery and DOM. Pick one scheme and stick with it and you'll do better. You can do this whole thing in one line with jQuery, since it loops automatically.

Comment: The basic lesson here is 1) do your research, and 2) don't mix JS and jQuery arbitrarily together, you tend to end up confusing yourself. Choose a style and stick to it throughout. Most applications don't really need jQuery these days - there are easy to use native DOM functions for the vast majority, and easy-to-research little polyfills for the rest.

Comment: @ADyson LOL, we started the same, then ended up with the opposite recommendations :)

Comment: @Barmar lol, it's a matter of opinion I guess. I loved jQuery for many years, but if I was just starting out I doubt I would need to bother with it now.

Comment: Error message: jQuery.Deferred exception: parent.find is not a function TypeError: parent.find is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Comment: So I should change .find() to .querySelector()?

Comment: If you want to use JS instead of jQuery there, then yes. And then also look at replacing the attr - see the duplicate for details of what you'd need to do.